# Finding minimum of n numbers with n^2 processors in constant time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing

Given an array with n numbers and n^2 processors find the minimum element in O(1) time complexity. I got a O(log n) solution. Can this be done?

Comment: With n processes you get O(log n) for reductions.

Comment: So isn't it possible to get in constant time complexity?

Comment: Maybe have a look at Rabenseifner: Optimization of Collective Reduction Operations http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.72.954&rep=rep1&type=pdf for example.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in constant time on a CRCW PRAM, but I suspect that you already knew that.

Comment: No ... Could you please throw some light about it? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have an initial array R of size n initialized to 0s. Assign each pair(Ai, Aj) of elements, (n^2 in total) to each of the n^2 processors for all 1<=i, j <= n. Each processor would check whether Ai > Aj. If so, then it would write 1 in R[i]. All these would be done parallel. Then we would have only one 0 in R. And the result would be input_array[index_of_zero_in_R]. The runtime is O(1).